# Simulink/StateFlow error with my Clock

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I created this state machine chart in Simulink using the StateFlow :

There are two states (S1,S2), one of which (S1) has 3 nested parallel FSM , each one has 4 states (SS1, SS2, SS2, SS4) , I put a default state in all of the 3 FSMs (SS1), and in the main two states (default S2).

To test the main FSM (S1,S2) , I used signal builder for all my inputs/events. One of the inputs is a square wave which is a clock event for my main FSM (1 Hz) and the duration of the simulation is 50 sec.

The problem i have is that i can see in the signal builder that i have a square wave, however when i put scope to that clock i see one square wave (extending from 0 to 49.5 second then drops to 0) .

[image]

Where is my clock ? what isn't it feeding my FSM properly ?

Here is the FSM:

[image]

The orthogonal sub-states are :

[image]

in details:

[image]

in in between S1  and S2

[image]

One of the signal builder , which has the Clock signal is:

[image]

The other has the following signals:

[image]

Comment: What Solver are you using, and what step size is being used?  Also, why do you define your Clock as going from 0->2 then convert it to boolean (which inherently is 0->1)?

Comment: solver is ode3. Regarding the clock, I suppose you have to use the converter so that they are boolean since I defined the three events clock and two other "rising edge" inputs. I am not sure if they have to be boolean. The 0-2 that's something created by simulink , im not sure why either...i put the amplitude of 1 of a 50Hz square wave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the default step size with ode3.  When using a fixed-step solver the `auto` step size is calculated as `(StopTime-StartTime)/50`.  In your case this gives a step size of 1.

Since at t = 0,1,2,3,...49 the `Clock` has a value of 2, that's what you see in the scope.
At t =50 the `Clock` has a value of 0, and that's what you're seeing in the scope.

You need to go to the `Solver Panel` of the `Simulaton->Model Configuration Parameters` pull-down menu.
Then open up the `Additional Options` option and change the step size to something smaller, such as 0.01.

Alternatively (depending on your other requirements) you could use a variable step solver.